# QUERY - One string in several columns

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

While there's [no IN in google sheets unlike in SQL](http://codingisforlosers.com/google-sheets-query-function/), I'm not looking for several strings in one column. I'm looking for one string in several columns.

So what's the shortcut of

> =QUERY($A:$K, "select A where B contains '"&N1&"' or C contains '"&N1&"' or D contains'"&N1&"' or E contains '"&N1&"' or F contains '"&N1&"' or G contains '"&N1&"' or H contains '"&N1&"' or I contains '"&N1&"' or J contains '"&N1&"' or K contains '"&N1&"'",3)

?

I'm hoping for something like

> =QUERY($A:$K, "select A where B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K contains '"&N1&"'",3)

[Cross-posted to Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/105243/88163)

Comment: @SloanThrasher Cmiiw, but that's the first one?

Comment: Can you add an example sheet link at the end, it will fetch proper results.

Comment: You can also do it with an array formula - can post it if you give us some test data.

Comment: @TomSharpe is it still going to be one cell only? Or do i need more cells?

Comment: @Vasim is it still going to be one cell only? Or do i need more cells?

Comment: Yes, it's a single cell formula but needs quite a bit of computation so wouldn't recommend for thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK two ways you might try

An array formula which tots up the number of matches in each row

```
=query({A:A,arrayformula(mmult(n(isnumber(find(N1,B:K))),transpose(column(B:K))^0))},"select Col1 where Col2>0")
```

or a hacky way which is like the workaround for a join in the reference in your question

```
=query(A:K,"select A where B contains '"&N1&"'" & arrayformula(concatenate(" or "&char(column(C:K)+64)& " contains '"&N1&"'")))
```

(works for single-letter column references only but may be quicker than the first one).

Comment: Oh sigh already implemented long version. Lol thanks Tom Sharpe ^-^ I'll try to see if I'll do this next time